# Finding Percentages of elements inside an ArrayList<model>

Tags: java, arraylist

So I am doing a project which I want to built a library with two ArrayLists one of the ArrayList'<'Book'>' BookList contains an element named quantity has to greater or equivalent to zero if the quantity of the book is above zero another element called status in the BookList is set to In-stock if it's equal to zero it's set to borrowed. I'm trying to create a method that looks at the BookList and shows the percentage of books that are borrowed. I have done this by going through the list and each time it finds a book with quantity below 1 in other words 0 the counter goes up by one so in the end I just substract the counter from the BookList.size(), divide the result with the BookList.size(), multiply it by 100 and fially print it.

Main Class

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);
    int uinput;
    Library nag;
    try{
    nag = new Library();
    do{
        System.out.println("Type 1 to add a book.");
        System.out.println("Type 2 to show how many books are borrowed.");
        uinput = keyb.nextInt();
        if (uinput==1){
            nag.addBook();
        }
        if (uinput==2){
            nag.statistics();
        }
    }while (uinput > 0);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Invalid entry.");
    }
}//end of main
}//end of class
```

Book Class

```
public class Book {

    private String Title;
    private String Author;
    private String ISBN;
    private String Publisher;
    private String Publication_Date;
    private String Price;
    private int Quantity;
    private String Status;

    public Book(){
        Title= "";
        Author="";
        ISBN="";
        Publisher="";
        Publication_Date="";
        Price="";
        Quantity=1;
        Status="IN-STOCK";
    }

    //getters
    public String gettitle(){return Title;}
    public String getauthor(){return Author;}
    public String getisbn(){return ISBN;}
    public String getpublisher(){return Publisher;}
    public String getpublication_date(){return Publication_Date;}
    public String getprice(){return Price;}
    public int getquantity(){return Quantity;}
    public String getstatus(){return Status;}

    //setters
    public void settitle(String t){Title = t;}
    public void setauthor(String a){Author = a;}
    public void setisbn(String is){ISBN = is;}
    public void setpublisher(String p){Publisher = p;}
    public void setpublication_date(String pd){Publication_Date = pd;}
    public void setprice(String pr){Price = pr;}
    public void setquantity(int q){Quantity = q;}
    public void setstatus(String s){Status = s;}

}//end of class
```

Library Class

```
public class Library {

private ArrayList<Book> BookList;

public Library(){
    BookList = new ArrayList<Book>();
}//end of constructor 1

public Library(ArrayList<Book> l) {
    BookList = l;
}//end of constructor 3

public void addBook(){
    try{
        Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);
        Book bo = new Book();

        System.out.println("Type the title: ");
        String title_input;
        title_input = keyb.nextLine();
        bo.settitle(title_input);

        System.out.println("Type the author: ");
        String author_input;
        author_input = keyb.nextLine();
        bo.setauthor(author_input);

        System.out.println("Type the isbn: ");
        String isbn_input;
        isbn_input = keyb.nextLine();
        bo.setisbn(isbn_input);

        System.out.println("Type the publisher: ");
        String publisher_input;
        publisher_input = keyb.nextLine();
        bo.setpublisher(publisher_input);

        System.out.println("Type the publication date: ");
        String publication_date_input;
        publication_date_input = keyb.nextLine();
        bo.setpublication_date(publication_date_input);

        System.out.println("Type the price: ");
        String price_input;
        price_input = keyb.nextLine();
        bo.setprice(price_input);

        System.out.println("Type the quantity: ");
        int quantity_input = Integer.parseInt(keyb.nextLine());
        if (quantity_input >= 0){
            bo.setquantity(quantity_input);
            if (quantity_input > 0){
                bo.setstatus("IN_STOCK");
            }
            if(quantity_input == 0){
                bo.setstatus("BORROWED");
            }
            BookList.add(bo);
            System.out.println("Book added successfully.");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Invalid entry");
    }//end of addBook() 

public void statistics(){
    Book bo = new Book();
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < BookList.size();i++){
        bo= BookList.get(i);
        int holdquantity = bo.getquantity();
        if (holdquantity  < 1){
            counter++;
        }  
    }
    double substraction=BookList.size() - counter;
    double division= substraction/BookList.size();
    double percentage = division * 100;
    System.out.print(percentage + "%");
}//end of statistics()
}//end of class
```

The problem is that it keeps printing 100.0% when I have a book with quantity of zero and another book with quantity above zero.
So I wanted to know if the problem lies within this code or elsewhere.

Comment: What's with your for-loop condition ? for(int i=0; BookList.size();i++)

Comment: My bad forgot to write it here but I edited it.

Comment: Go accept the edit, your <String> is not being escaped, and for loop condition was corrected.

Comment: Can you post, all of your code, I will help you fix this.

Comment: Your for loop is wrong, try this for (into I=0 ; I<BookList.size();i++)

Comment: @Santosh what's wrong exactly ?

Comment: @GCP, it should be I less than instead of I greater than.

Comment: @Santosh It is i < BookList.size(), I edited his code 4 mins ago.

Comment: Display counter variable after for loop.

Comment: Have you debugged through your code? Also I assume you actually have a semi-colon after the `counter++`.

Comment: @Santosh after the for loop counter says 0 so we found what was wrong with it

Comment: @GCP That's all of it.

Comment: Change your Library class code with this: https://pastebin.com/HSHePMAQ  and read my answer below to see what I changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your Book class is as follows:

```
package com.company;

public class Book {

    private int quantity;

    public Book(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

And your Main is as follows:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main (String[]args) {

        List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>(){{
            add(new Book(4));
            add(new Book(0));
            add(new Book(3));
            add(new Book(7));
            add(new Book(0));
            add(new Book(0));
            add(new Book(1));
            add(new Book(9));
            add(new Book(0));
            add(new Book(5));
        }};

        int booksOutOfStock = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < bookList.size(); i++) {
            if (bookList.get(i).getQuantity() == 0)
                booksOutOfStock++;
        }

        double percentage = 100d / bookList.size() * booksOutOfStock;

        System.out.printf("Out of total %d books, %d are out of stock, which makes %.2f%%", bookList.size(), booksOutOfStock,
                                                                                                        percentage);
    }
}
```

So check this code, compare it to yours and see where could the error be, or post complete code here so we can help more.

Output of code above:

> Out of total 10 books, 4 are out of stock, which makes 40.00%

OK, so after you posted your code I reviewed it, and apart from doing some things the hard way, your code is "working", all I had to do was add a closing brace in Library class at the end of addBook() method after catch block:

```
catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Invalid entry");
    } --> } <--- (added)

    //end of addBook()
```

And I fixed your percentage code logic, you code would print out the number of non borrowed books as borrowed percentage, here is that code changed:

```
    double division= (double)counter/BookList.size();
    double percentage = division * 100;
    System.out.printf("%.2f", percentage);
```